# Silverlight binding - how to make StringFormat option multiline in XAML

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am using a pretty long `StringFormat` for my bound tooltip and am currenly trying to make it multiline in XAML.

While I was able to make literal ToolTip multiline using `&#xa;` for line breaks I am unable to get it to work with `StringFormat`.

I am trying to get following code to give me a tooltip with line break:

```
ToolTipService.Tooltip= {Binding Property,StringFormat='FORMAT WITH LINE BREAK {0}'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I got correct answer here:

[official silverlight forums link](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/233663.aspx/1?Silverlight%20binding%20how%20to%20make%20StringFormat%20option%20multiline%20in%20XAML)

We can use `&#x0a;` for line break.

or :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=a, 
         StringFormat='First Line \{0\} &#x0a; Second Line'}" />
```

Difference is pretty big.. This one works.

Answer (score 3):

In string format output, have you tried using \r instead to insert carriage returns?

The only reason these encodings exist is to allow special character values to be placed in XML/Xaml.

The `&#x0a;` is just an encoding for hex character A = decimal 10 = \r (carriage return).

*Another one of interest is `&#x0d;` which is character D = decimal 13 = \n (newline).*

Note Hex encoding normally requires pairs of digits so `&#xd;` was the actual error.

Comment: '\r' is displayed as r . '\n' is displayed as n '\\r' is displayed as '\r'

Comment: That's just wrong... '\r' would never display as 'r' unless you are using an @ prefixed string. Can you provide your String.Format statement to check?

Comment: can you provide a working StringFormat that breaks into two lines tooltip? I am talking about StringFormat from some kind of following code: ToolTipService.Tooltip= {Binding Property,StringFormat='FORMAT WITH LINE BREAK'} If format contains \r its displayed as r